# Azure App Configuration Push Task - How can I deploy key vault reference values in azure app configuration using this task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-app-configuration

I am using AzureAppConfigurationPush@1 task for deploying app configuration values in different environment. I am able to add key value pairs sucessfully but I am not finding ways to add Key vault reference.

```
-task: AzureAppConfigurationPush@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azureResourceManager }}'
          ConfigstoreName: '${{ parameters.appConfigName }}'
          ConfigurationFile: '${{parameters.configFileName }}'
          Separator: ','
          Strict: false
```

I am passing config file name as parameters in which I am giving Json which I export from azure app configuration. When I export app configuration values, key value pair contains uri and its value like this:
"AppInsightsKey": "{"uri":"https://.vault.azure.net/secrets/AppInsightsKey"}"

But this doesn't go as Key vault reference using push task but considered as a string completely.

Can you help me understand hot to push key vault reference so that it will automatically create a reference if possible?

Answer (score 2):

The push task takes [content type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline#parameters) as a parameter. If you want to create key-vault references, you'll need to specify the content type of a key vault reference for the settings being pushed.

Key Vault Reference content type: application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.keyvaultref+json;charset=utf-8

Comment: Yes this works!!! Thanks. There is one limitation though, we can not have Key vault reference and key value pair in the same configuration file as we need to additionally use content type as KV reference. It needs two push task one for key value pair and one for kay vault reference. Both referencing to their respective config files

Answer (score -2):

It seems that that is a problem with [Azure App Configuration Push extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureAppConfiguration.azure-app-configuration-task-push).

You have to contact with that team to report the problem.